# JQuantlib missing extensions

Tags: java, netbeans, java-ee-5

I am working on a big project that requires massive financial calculations, I am using
Netbeans IDE 7.3 with a default web application of Java EE 5 (not a maven application)
,My application server is tomcat 7 I am using jsps and servlets my OS is windows 7.

I downloaded and added the jquantlib binary to my application, but when I run it keeps saying that it needs the slf4j-api extension that is not found so i download it also and added its jar to my project but still the error persists.

How can I solve this ? and can anyone give me some guidelines on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that jquantlib requires slf4j-api version 1.4.0 in the jar manifest:

(from MANIFEST.MF in jquantlib.jar)

```
    Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.jquantlib
    Extension-List: slf4j-api
    slf4j-api-Extension-Name: slf4j-api
    slf4j-api-Implementation-Version: 1.4.0
```

Tomcat will try to use the version of slf4j-api that you're including in your app, but it's likely that what you've included isn't actually compatible. See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.34/org/apache/catalina/util/Extension.java#Extension.isCompatibleWith%28org.apache.catalina.util.Extension%29 for details.

Bottom line - try to use slf4j-api version 1.4.0 in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the lines from the MANIFEST.MF file that mention the sfl4j